# C++: Short question regarding switch and break

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Example:

```
switch( x )
{
case y:
 if ( true )
 {
    break;
 }
 cout << "Oops";
 break;
}
```

If the switch statement selects `y`, will `Oops` be written to the standard output?
- Is `break` in `switch` statements a dynamic keyword like continue which can be called under conditions or static like a closing bracket `}`?

Comment: Why didn't you just compile and test it yourself?

Comment: Since when is it wise to trust one specific implementation?

Comment: A good compiler would tell you that you've unreachable code here.

Comment: -1 Why didn't you just compile and test it yourself?

Comment: @All of the flamers: I compiled it before and it worked. I was not sure why, still. Also I have asked about how break works in this case. -1

Comment: Good question. Missing this point caused the famous ATT bug! See slides 20-21 in http://www.cs.drexel.edu/~spiros/teaching/SE320/slides/introduction.ppt

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`break` breaks out of an enclosing `switch`, `while`, `for`, or `do ... while`. It doesn't break out of an enclosing `if` or bare block. Pretty much exactly like `continue`.

It's certainly not part of the required syntax of a switch statement (like a close-brace is part of the syntax of blocks). `break` is a statement, essentially meaning "transfer execution to the point after the end of the innermost breakable construct".

Answer (score 1):

No, `Oops` will not written out, the `break` jumps behind this statement.

You can use `break` statements conditionally just fine, you only have to watch out when you create nested statements that also support `break` (i.e. loops).

Answer (score 0):

`break` is absolutely dynamic. So, if you write `if (false) break;` your `Oops` would be written out.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `break` in this case as a `goto end_of_switch`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not be printed in your case. `break` only breaks from switches and loops, not conditionals or functions or arbitrary enclosing scopes. Therefore, a more relevant question would be whether Oops is printed in *this* case:

```
switch( x )
{
case y:
 for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
 {
    break;
 }
 cout << "Oops";
 break;
}
```

And the answer *here* is yes, it will. The `break` will break out of the `for`, not the `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

No. It would break out of the switch construct. "break" is used to come out of the innermost loop construct or switch construct. So, in your case the "oops" is not printed out on the screen. If you want that to happen, in your code, you could use if(false) instead of if(true).